# Session / working set in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, session, visual-studio-2012, ide

Is there any way of saving a "session" / "working set" in visual studio. By session ( ex: session in Notepad++ ) I mean group a bunch of files that I'm viewing so I can save and re-open that same set of files. Similar concept exists in eclipse "working set" which applies to projects ofcourse.

Comment: ever find anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

The way I am able to create such a session is:

1. Enable launching debugger automatically for the .exe to be debugged using "Image File Execution Options" in registry (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). The .exe may be any executable, e.g. notepad.exe, in case you are not interested in debugging.
2. Run the .exe.
3. In the "Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger" dialog that is displayed, select "New instance of Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx" and click Yes.
4. In the new instance, open the files as required and do 'Save All' to save the .sln file at desired location. Your session, including open files and breakpoints, will be saved along with the .sln in .suo file.